# Heprledger Composer REST: old models in endpoints

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I deleted all the containers and started the network and REST from scratch. But endpoints do not match what is written in the model (a very old version of the network is displayed).

This is definitely not a browser cache problem. I do not understand what's wrong.

Where does REST take these old models? What do I need to update or delete?

Comment: Did you resolve this using `composer network ping` and `composer network download` ?

Comment: @RThatcher It did not help: https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=WXPDjzs4eSQYX5Qav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just needed to delete old images with `docker rmi $(docker images -aq)` and start network again.